# The prefix 'com.example.' is meant as a placeholder and should not be used

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile

I always get this Warning

> *Package Name:* The prefix 'com.example.' is meant as a placeholder and should not be used

Is this something I should worry about ? Or is it just an friendly notification to developers from the IDE ? Would like to know the issues I would encounter if I change the

[image]

Comment: Screenshot available here. [link] (http://sathyanarayanan.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/1stquery.png)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like just a friendly message to developers. `com.example` will be added by eclipse as a placeholder to show you how you should structure your package name.
You might consider changing it to something unique like `in.sathyanarayanan.accelerometertesting` if you are going to use this code for anything serious.

But given that the name of the project is `accelerometertesting` I imagine it's not a serious application, so you don't really need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is relevant if you plan on putting your app on Google Play and if the package name you refer to is the one being used in the projects manifest.

More information about the package name and it's effect (when that package name is the one in the manifest): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html under package

> The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application. It's also the default name for the application process (see the  element's process process attribute) and the default task affinity of an activity (see the  element's taskAffinity attribute).

Comment: Or if you call it from another package